# Differentiate the Function: $y=\frac{e^x}{1-e^x}$

Tags: calculus

$y=\frac{e^x}{1-e^x}$

Utilize the quotient rule:

$y'=\frac{(1-e^x)\cdot\ e^x\ - [e^x(-e^x) ]}{(1-e^x)^2}$

$y'=\frac{(1-e^x)\cdot\ e^x\ - e^x(+e^x) }{(1-e^x)^2}$

I am confused how to solve the problem from this point. Can I factor out the negative sign in the numerator? If so why?

Comment: A better option will be to take $e^x$ common from both the numerator and the denominator. After that it's a matter of simple differentiation using chain rule.

Comment: @Gummybears $e^x$ is not in the denominator. You have a +1.

Comment: @wythagoras Sorry but failed to understand what you mean. After taking that factor common we will get $\frac{1}{e^{-x} - 1}$ which I believe to be much easier as there is no need to apply quotient/product rule.

Comment: @Gummybears Sorry I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\frac{e^x}{1-e^x}$$ Differentiating it with respect to $x$ and using quotient rule, we have,
$$y'=\frac{(1-e^x)\cdot\ e^x\ - [e^x(-e^x) ]}{(1-e^x)^2}$$

$$y'=\frac{(1-e^x)\cdot\ e^x\ + e^x(e^x) }{(1-e^x)^2}$$
$$\implies y'= \frac{e^x-e^{2x} + e^{2x}}{(1-e^x)^2}$$
$$\implies y'=\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$y=-1+(1-e^x)^{-1} \implies y'=e^x(1-e^x)^{-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your third line is wrong, it should be (as negative times negative equals positive)

$$y'=\frac{(1-e^x)\cdot\ e^x\ + e^x(+e^x) }{(1-e^x)^2}$$

which is equal to

$$\frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to write the function as $$y=\frac{-(1-e^x)}{1-e^x}-\frac{1}{1-e^x}$$

$$y=-1-\frac{1}{1-e^x}$$

Now use the chain rule:

$$y'=-(1-e^x)^{-2}\cdot-e^x=e^x(1-e^x)^{-2}=\frac{e^x}{(1-e^x)^{2}}$$